# How to download music file in ionic that no other app can access that file?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, download, drm

I build an app that downloads the music file so that the user can listen to that file offline.
But I want user can only listen to that file on my app, no other app can access that file.

I heard of using DRM protection, but I don't know how to use it.
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can encrypt the file with this plugin : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-encryption

Comment: you can store songs in App's db so that only your app can access that data.you can use sqlite fit that purpose

Comment: most welcome @Mohit

Comment: @Mohit cloud you please tell me how did you download songs in private folder. i want to achieve same scenario